# Using FS88 futronic fingerprint reader with python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to use the Futronic FS88 fingerprint reader with Python, but I've made little progress so far.

The first issue is that there isn't satisfactory documentation available from Futronic.

I'm referring to the following resources: https://github.com/erikssm/futronics-fingerprint-reader/blob/master/ftrScanAPI.h, which contains the source code, and [Get image from a fingerprint using Python and Ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533147/get-image-from-a-fingerprint-using-python-and-ctypes), which provides an example.

I know that I need to use ctypes and have managed to establish some communication. However, I would like to do something simpler than the example given in the provided link.

Does anyone know where I can find decent documentation?

So far, I would like to accomplish the following basic tasks:

```
Open the connection with the reader.
Perform the fingerprint scan.
Save the image as a BMP file.
Close the connection with the reader.
```

Comment: Another sample: [\[SO\]: python ctypes issue on different OSes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185316/4788546).